# Way to test user-agent string against list of bad bots?

Tags: python, linux, apache2, debian, user-agent

I'm denying bad bots to my Apache server via a long (160+) list of bad-bot user-agent strings in an Apache config file as so:

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "AhrefsBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Baiduspider" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Exabot" bad_bot
...
<Directory />
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=bad_bot
</Directory>
</IfModule>
```

However, some legitimate clients are being blocked even though their user-agent strings don't seem to match any of the bad-bot user-agents, like:

```
"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)"
```

**QUESTION:  Is there a way to find out which bad-bot user-agent string is matched that causes a request to be denied, such as through the logs, or perhaps a way to feed the above user-agent string against the list of bad bots to see what is causing the match?**

Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, you have a list of 1600+ bad bots. That sounds like a complete waste of CPU cycles. If these bots are truly "bad bots", what's stopping them from using desktop or mobile browser User-Agent strings, and becoming undetectable by your config :) Now to answer your question, you should use regex to match your bots, so you will avoid substring matching of the mod_setenvif. Your SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "AhrefsBot" bad_bot would become SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^AhrefsBot$" bad_bot, so your false positives will disappear after this.

Comment: 160, not 1600...my bad.

Comment: Does it work fine if you use regex pattern?

Comment: https://user-agents.top/post/2022-09-04-how-to-block-unwanted-bots/ has a recipe for blocking the majority of bots by whitelisting allowed in robots.txt. It's the simplest solution